# React Native cloned child component is not being rerendered as props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a custom Navigator component. I need to provide Navigator's stack components a `navigator` prop to allow them to push and pop scenes like this:

```
this.props.navigator.push(<Product id='4815'>)
this.props.navigator.pop()
```

In order to achieve this result, inside my Navigator's class, I've used `React.cloneElement()`:

```
class Navigator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { stack: [this._addNavigator(props.children)] }
  }

  _addNavigator(scene) {
    return React.cloneElement(scene, {
      navigator: {
        push: this.push,
        pop: this.pop,
        popToRoot: this.popToRoot
      }
    })
  }

  push(scene) {
    this.setState({
      stack: [...this.state.stack, this._addNavigator(scene)]
    })
  }

  ...

}
```

Everything works just fine, except for a particular scenario.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = { toggle: false }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
        }}>
          <Text>Toggle</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Navigator>
          <SampleScene backgroundColor={this.state.toggle ? 'green' : 'black'} />
        </Navigator>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

When I pass some mutable prop to the Navigator children, as soon as the prop changes, the child component does not rerender. In the example above, SampleScene's backgroundColor stays black (because App class initial state for `toggle` is set to `false`), despite the user pressing the Toggle button. It seems like the SampleScene's `render()` method is called just once. How could I troubleshoot this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Inside Navigator, I had to intercept new props via componentWillReceiveProps. Setting the stack to newProps' children via setState method made the Navigator rerender properly.